# if then statement equivalent in php

Tags: php, ti-basic

I am newish to php. But when i learned to program it was on a TI-83 Calculator. with the TI83 their was an if-then statements the could be used. I am writing some code to check if a directory is already created and if not create it. I need it to run the last half of the code either way. here is the code.

```
<?php
$dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/$_POST[Itemid]/" ;
if (!file_exists($dir) and !is_dir($dir)) {
    $upload_dir = mkdir($dir, 0777);
}else{
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
    $filetemp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"][$key];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"][$key];
   if (file_exists($dir . $filename))
  {
  echo $filename . " already exists. <br><br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $filename . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $filetype . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($filesize / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Temporarily Stored in: " . $filetemp . "<br>";
  move_uploaded_file($filetemp,"$dir/$filename");
  echo "uploaded the file \"" . $filename. "\" to the \"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/\" Directory<br>" ;
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Inventory");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO ListPics (`1`, `Item_ItemID`)
VALUES
('$dir$filename', '$_POST[Itemid]')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo ($filename. " added to Database<br><br>");

mysqli_close($con);
  }
  }
  }
  }
?>
```

Yes I know this code is not secure. It will not ever see the interweb(Reverently bows head and says "Thank you Al Gore") It will sit snugly behind a VPN for personal use only. I just need to know how to execute the PHP equivalent of If Then Statements

Comment: Your `if`/`else` structures look fine; what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need it to execute the else after the if even when the if is not true.

Comment: If you want to execute the else part even if is not true then don't use else.

Comment: This is simple: `if(condition) { /* do something if condition is true */ } else { /* do something else if condition is false */ } /* do other stuff either way */`

Comment: HAHA I was way over thinking it. Copy and paste that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: I think you should read this chapter from the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php the manual is a must when you are learning php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple:

```
if(condition) {
    /* do something if condition is true */
}
else {
    /* do something else if condition is false */
}
/* do other stuff either way */
```

You only need the `else` if there is something that you want to do *only* if the condition is false. If you want to do it either way, then don't use `else` at all.